# Configuring Apple Magic Trackpad in 12.04

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, trackpad, magic-trackpad

How should I configure a Magic Trackpad in 12.04 to

- ignore my thumb at the bottom of the trackpad
- change scrolling speed
- change gesture functions (e.g. have three-finger tap = middle-click), if doing so is possible

?

I tried installing gsynaptics and using gpointing-device-settings, but its palm-detection and scrolling settings do nothing. (In fact, it shows scrolling as disabled, even though scrolling is enabled in System Settings > Mouse and Touchpad, and definitely works.)

Comment: Incidentally, what settings is System Settings > Mouse and Touchpad actually changing? Something in the kernel, something in xorg, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Magic trackpad is basically a synaptic touchpad inside.  Many parameters can be adjusted with `synclient`, for example,

```
synclient TapButton3=2
```

will set three-finger tap to the middle button.